# Animating SVG line about endpoint with Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, snap.svg

I have the following code which when you click the gray semi-circle there are two animations that happen, I am very close to my intended outcome, however the line path animation animates about a point but that point seems to move at the end, I would like it to rotate about it's endpoint so that i doesn't move out of the circle that endpoint is in.

It is much clearer in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kitsondevelopment/14e107mt/3/) to see what I am talking about and the issue at hand.

** You have to click the gray circle to activate the animation **

```js
console.clear();

var loop = "M31,201.1C16.6,118.8,69.1,40.5,150.7,26c32.5-5.8,64.5-1.6,93.7,14.5c59.1,32.6,88.4,94,77.1,159.1";
var pin = "M180.4,193.3c-1.8,0-3.5-0.9-4.4-2.6c-1.3-2.4-0.5-5.5,2-6.8L309.8,111c2.4-1.3,5.5-0.5,6.8, 2c1.3,2.4,0.5,5.5-2,6.8l-131.8,72.9C182.1,193.1,181.2,193.3,180.4,193.3z";
var circle_svg = "M-224.1,227.9c-5.1,5.1-5.1,13.4,0,18.5s13.4,5.1,18.5,0s5.1-13.4,0-18.5C-210.8,222.8-219,222.8-224.1,227.9z";

var loopLength = Snap.path.getTotalLength(loop);

console.log(loopLength);

var s = Snap();

circle = s.path({
  path: loop,
  fill: "gray",
  stroke: "#c00",
  strokeWidth: 0,
  strokeLinecap: "round"
});

var g = s.gradient("l(0, 0, 1, 1)#80DFFE-#0CA5EE-#07A3EE");

circleOutline = s.path({
  path: Snap.path.getSubpath(loop, 0, 0),
  stroke: g,
  fillOpacity: 0,
  strokeWidth: 0,
  strokeLinecap: "round"
});



circle_middle = s.path({
  path: circle_svg,
  stroke: "#000000",
  fill: "#ffffff",
  strokeWidth: 5,


});

pin_line = s.path({
  path: pin,
  fill: "#000000"

});

// +"t"+[translateX,translateY]


circle_middle.attr({
  transform: "t" + [400, -65]
});
pin_line.attr({
  transform: 'r-170,180,180'
});
circle.click(function(e) {

  Snap.animate(0, loopLength,
    function(step) { //step function

      circleOutline.attr({
        path: Snap.path.getSubpath(loop, 0, step),
        strokeWidth: 25
      });

    }, // end of step function
    800 //duration

  ); //Snap.animate

  pin_line.animate({
    transform: 'r30,180,180',
    translate: '20, 20, 85, 85'
  }, 1000);


}); //click the circle
```

```css
svg {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I _think_ it's just that your pin, loop, and circle paths don't share a center point (i.e. I don't think the problem is the fault of the code that animates them).

Comment: Hmm, @maxStarkenburg I can edit the svg original in sketch, is that the right place to start to fix this, do you have a suggested solution?

Comment: Yeah, I've only worked on stuff in Illustrator, which I know has alignment tools. Haven't used Sketch before, but I would think alignment would be a rather basic tool in any vector image editor.

Comment: Errr, maybe never mind (ish). I'll write up an answer to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there was indeed an alignment issue, and I tried to fix that in Illustrator, then came back to your example, and realized how some of those transforms in the JS actually work, and was able to adjust them to finally look correct, but when I tried just adjusting the transforms using your paths, I couldn't get it right, even when applying t(ranslations) to the pin_line in addition to rotations.  So it's either a combination of the paths needing to be replaced with some fine-tuning of that rotation points, or it's that I just don't fully understand how to work the snapsvg code.  :) In any case, I got a fiddle working that incorporates some of my new path coordinates made in Illustrator and some changes to the JS: https://jsfiddle.net/14e107mt/4/ In addition to the paths changing, it comments out the translation of `circle_middle`'s translation (since it's now aligned there by default), and changes the `pin_line` rotation coordinates to

```
pin_line.attr({ transform: 'r-170 176 172' });
```

and

```
pin_line.animate({ transform: 'r30 176 172' }, 1000 );
```

instead of `180 180`.